# Bash cron job doesn't execute like it does on command line

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, cron

I've written a bash script that executes a python script to write a file to a directory, then sends that file to Amazon S3. When I execute the script from the command line it executes perfectly, but when I run it with cron, the file writes to the directory, but never gets sent to S3. I must be doing something wrong with cron.

Here is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#python script that exports file to home directory
python some_script.py

#export file created by python to S3
s3cmd put /home/bitnami/myfile.csv s3://location/to/put/file/myfile.csv
```

Like I said before, manually executing works fine using `./bash_script.sh`. When I set up the cron job, the file writes to the directory, but never gets sent to S3.

my cron job is:

`18 * * * * /home/bitnami/bash_script.sh`

Am I using cron incorrectly? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron looks OK, however your path to the .py file will not be found.

You will have to add a path or home like:

```
location=/home/bitnami/
python $location/some_script.py
```

Also s3cmd needs to be located correctly:

```
/bin/s3cmd
```

Alternative might also need to load your user environment first before executing the script to find username/password/ssh key for s3cmd

Comment: The .py file is found because it outputs the file correctly, but I should probably get in the habit of using this. the second part makes sense. I'll let you know how it works. Thanks

Comment: Watch that the py output is not your old data from a test run.