# Script that does mysql commands not working with cron job

Tags: mysql, bash, cron

I have a bash script that grabs a file from an FTP, unrars it, inserts it into a MySQL db and then does a few queries on that database. Now the script runs perfectly when i manually run it but I need it to be ran every day at a certain time. So of course i put it in a cron job. Now I know that the cron is running because at the end of the script i have it echo a line to a log file and it has been doing that. However, MySQL commands are not being done in the script.

Basically it will grab the file from the ftp, and unrar it, then not load the file or do the mysql commands, and then it moves the file to a different directory and does my log echo.

TLDR: My bash script that contains bash commands and MySQL will only do the bash commands when put in a cron. Will do all commands when ran manually.

Comment: Can you show us the mysql query please.

Comment: There are multiple ones but there is one of them: 

for f in /root/XXXX/*.txt
do
 mysql -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"$f"' INTO TABLE XXX FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES" -uXXX -pXXX --database=XXXXX
done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you confident that the script runs as the same user when you run it on the command line and when it gets run by the cron job?  Most likely not, most likely not even the same group..  You may need to adjust your script to sudo to some other user, and to check the environmental variables..

Comment: i think this is it! Thank you so much! I'll try it out and see if it works.

edit: I just made a script to do a simple select and added a cronjob for it and it worked, so sadly that is not it.

Comment: Mmmm.  And you're logging in as the very same mysql user in both methods?  Also, I've found that cron jobs for different time frames may well not run the same way in debian, which makes ubuntu suspect as well, so are you sure your test is completely accurate that way?  I'd still look to some user incompatibility rather than anything wrong with your script, obviously...

Comment: check this angle out too, @MichaelJC https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086371/bash-cron-job-doesnt-execute-like-it-does-on-command-line

Comment: I'm actually using root for all of this @George M

Comment: then it must be a different environment setup..  Can you write every variable you can possibly think of to a log file?  Can you add abundant debugging statements and get those logged?  Apparently you do have access to a log file, right?  Sorry, groping around as if I was you there, wish I had an obvious solution :-).  But I'm afraid we've all been in this boat at some point..

Comment: So I let it run a couple days to see what happens exactly with the new logs and it looks like it runs every single command (including mysql ones) except for the load command. Is there something that could be preventing only the load command from working? Again, thanks for all the help!

Comment: I wonder @MichaelJC how big your load command is?  I mean how much data are you trying to load? Could there be a limit to how much a cron job can load up vs a live user?  Can you break up your input data into smaller chunks and try?  Some hosts for instance seem to limit at 50MB, and if you exceeded that it'd be possible that your entire command would fail rather than getting a partial load (although you would hope for some helpful error message either way).  And speaking of which, is there really no error message of any kind in your logs?

Comment: Also, I don't know how to quote from a comment elsewhere, but "Try running a cron job that simply records the environment that cron sets for you: /usr/bin/env > /tmp/env.cron."

Comment: Also, you're certain that a cron job is running bash, instead of the common 'sh' default?  Did you explicitly declare that with "SHELL=/bin/bash"?

Comment: I finally figured out what the problem was. The cronjob was taking my path for my load as a literal. What I mean by this is that when i did my for f in '/path/*.txt' it took it as /path/*.txt and of course that file did not exist. So i fixed it (probably horribly) by doing an ls > file.txt and then doing a while read on that file. However, I learned that i actually wasn't unrar'ing the files either since its taking it as a literal path as well. I still can't figure out how to unrar all the .rar files in a directory and have it work in the cron

Comment: Oh yeah, congratulations :-)!  Progress is good :-).  Probably not unrar'ing because you don't have correct permission for the cron user in that directory? Or next not enough space, since un-compressing often brings that up.

Comment: It looks like its the same as the load, its taking the path name as literal